# Display Power on hours of hard disk from shell

Tags: linux, hard-drive, shell

Is there a program which can display the power on hours of a hard disk from a *nix shell? I'm rewriting a server benchmark program, and this would be a useful value to compare.

Answer (score 2):

`smartctl` from the [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) package can display this information, provided the OS has "raw" access to the device. If you are using a hardware RAID, this information is typically not available without array-specific drivers and userland tools.

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to employ standard unix text processing tools to filter out the information you need.

Comment: Running it on my drive brings up `Device does not support SMART`

Comment: What type of drive is this and how is it connected to your system?

Comment: If you have a RAID controller you can try *MegaCLI*

Comment: It is 2x 1TB SATA2 drives connected to PERC H200 hardware RAID 1. It is part of a leased dedicated server.

Comment: PERC H200 is from DELL so you can use their OMSA tools http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA